# Create tag search in user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I'm new with rails!
I have a user model, and in my database i have an string field in the table user.
This is the schema:

```
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name",                   default: "",     null: false
    t.string   "email",                  default: "",     null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "",     null: false
    t.string   "about"
    t.string   "avatar"
    t.string   "cover"
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,      null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "confirmation_token"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.datetime "created_at",                              null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                              null: false
    t.string   "sex",                    default: "male", null: false
    t.string   "location"
    t.date     "dob"
    t.string   "phone_number"
    t.integer  "posts_count",            default: 0,      null: false
    t.string   "slug"
    t.string   "tag"
    t.integer  "point"
```

I would like to generate a Taxonomy with this field, and a criteria of searching users with similar tags, do you suggest me something for this action?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that a user will have multiple comma separated tags, I would recommend you to create a different model for tags.

There is an excellent gem for this purpose called acts_as_taggable_on.

You can easily implement the functionality to search users by tags using this gem.

Please find the link to the gem homepage on github

[Acts As taggable On](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your suggestion, i did it, but i cant save the info, you suggest me to save tag as a different model in my app? As a string, integer? What do you suggest me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved working with act as a taggable on. 
Thanks!